# Fill New Taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, taxonomy, wpdb, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I will explain my scenary and then my problema..
I have more than 10.000 products on my woocommerce categorized by differents name. IE car parts.
I need yo create a new type of taxonomy that I will use Custom Post Type UI to create a new categorization in adittion the others..
that's looks good.. I have my 10.000 products categorized by car parts and my new taxonomy i.e. car brands.

My problem now is how can I modify all those 10.000 products at ones to get them into the right brand each one.
So, is there a way to iterate the db and fill o edit that data to put them all at ones?

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

So! I solve this situation with: wp_set_post_terms.

I iterate my posts and for each one wp_set_post_terms make that part.

See here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_terms/

Now I have my categories from wp and my customs post with his own categories.